# Live "out of" or "in" your car?

Tags: prepositions

Why do people say "out of" in the following example and similar ones? Is it only NAmE?

> I was living out of my car back then.

Some might say that you should say "out of" since you're not always in your car, but a similar case could be made for a house. I'm not always in it, but say *I live in a house.*

I haven't been able to find anything relevant on the usage or origin.

Comment: Presumably the expression refers to someone forced to keep all their belongings in their car, so they have to go there for a change of clothes or whatever.

Comment: Both expressions are used.  "Out of" leaves a little leeway for where you actually sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it originates from the phrase living out of a suitcase. Supporting this is a [Google ngram plot](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=living%20out%20of%20his%20suitcase%2Cliving%20out%20of%20his%20car&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cliving%20out%20of%20his%20suitcase%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cliving%20out%20of%20his%20car%3B%2Cc0) showing the phrase with suitcase preceding car by almost 30 years.

Lexico defines [live out of a suitcase](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/live_out_of_a_suitcase) as

> Live or stay somewhere on a temporary basis and with only a limited
>   selection of one's belongings, typically because one's occupation
>   requires a great deal of traveling.

Living out of a car is typically done because one lacks a traditional residence, but the idea is similar in that all of one's belongings are in the car.

Comment: I think you are right. I always feel that "living out of a suitcase" implies that the person has all his belongings in a suitcase but sleeps in hotel and boarding house rooms. "Living out of a car" gives me the same impression but implies that the person has more belongings or, possibly, larger pieces of equipment.

Comment: It makes sense. I can live with it as a hyperbolic offshoot of "living out of a suitcase!" :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In USA, there is emerging community of co-called [van-dwellers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandwelling) who live in a van/minivan/car/RV either full time or part time (often several months), spending most of the time either camping on public lands for free, campgrounds, or "stealth-camping" in cities.

For example, [Quartzsite RV show](https://www.outdoorsy.com/blog/quartzsite-big-deal-world-rvs) brings together about 150 thousands people.

Saying "living out of (car/van/RV) means for those nomads means "my vehicle is my kitchen and bedroom, living room is outdoors".

Another saying they use is "I am not homeless - I am house-free" (if van/RV is their only residence, meaning they do not pay the mortgage).

RV = recreation vehicle = campervan.